# Jquery executing at all times

Tags: php, jquery, click, magento2, magento2.2

I have a dropdown switcher in order to change storeviews. I would like to implement a function done with PHP once an option from the dropdown is clicked.

I have been trying to implement this event via Jquery as below:

```
<?php if (count($block->getGroups()) > 1): ?>
<div class="switcher store switcher-store" id="switcher-store">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Select Store') ?></span></strong>
    <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
            <?php if ($_group->getId() == $block->getCurrentGroupId()): ?>
                <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
                     role="button"
                     tabindex="0"
                     data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                     data-toggle="dropdown"
                     data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
                     id="switcher-store-trigger">
                    <strong>
                        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_group->getName()) ?></span>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php foreach ($block->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
                <?php if (!($_group->getId() == $block->getCurrentGroupId())): ?>
                    <li class="switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='<?= $block->getTargetStorePostData($_group->getDefaultStore()); ?>'>
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_group->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
            $("#switcher-option").trigger("click", clickConfirm());
            function clickConfirm(){
                var isGood=confirm('You will lose your cart items if you switch between seasons!');
                if (isGood) {
                    <?php $seasonsHelper->getClearCart(); ?>
                } else {
                    <?php $this->getUrl('*');?>
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The store change works perfectly, but the confirm event appears on different places, not only when I select the dropdown button. If I add to cart, it also appears, when I load the page, It also appears.

I've been trying to accurate identifier with ".class" or "#id" but nothing works.

Is this the proper way to do it?

[image]

Comment: You do not have any element with ID `switcher-option` here, so `$("#switcher-option")` won’t select anything to begin with. And triggering an event in this place is probably not what you want to do here either. This should probably be something like `$(".switcher-option").on("click",function() { … });` instead.

Comment: hi, remove the brackets from clickConfirm in your click event: `$("#switcher-option").on("click", clickConfirm);`. if you leave brackets the function will auto-execute on load. Also use `on` insted of `trigger` as `trigger` will start an event instead of listening for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to your JS code:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
if( $("#switcher-option").lengh>0 ){ /// check for element existance
    $("#switcher-option").trigger("click", clickConfirm());
}

function clickConfirm(){
    var isGood=confirm('You will lose your cart items if you switch between seasons!');
    if (isGood) {
        <?php $seasonsHelper->getClearCart(); ?>
    } else {
        <?php $this->getUrl('*');?>
    }
}
```

});

Note: code is not tested, just shared the logic.